# How to store the data to the iPhone app

Tags: objective-c, ios

We developed the iphone app which will be used by employees of the diff. organizations (actually we have not made it enterprise app , instead we are going to put this app on app store for the charge) , **So whats we want is whenever the person will install the app, and the app will open first time , one pop up will come over there asking for the enter URL** (which will be the URL points to the server of that persons organization) , So going through code logic , what i want is when we will come to the login page in the view did load i want to check whether the URL is already stored in the app or not, if its not stored then i will give that pop up asking for enter URL, and if its stored then simply i will allow him to enter the login details.

My problem is how should i store that URL and where should i store that URL and How should i check whether that is already stored or not. I tried to store that URL with...  Where the urlfield.text is the URL i am going to store.

```
NSError *error;
    // For error information

    // Create file manager
    fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Point to Document directory
    documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() 
                          stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
    fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath];
    // File we want to create in the documents directory 
    // Result is: /Documents/file1.txt
    filePath = [documentsDirectory 
                stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file1.txt"];
    str=urlField.text;
    // Write the file
    [str writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES 
            encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    // Show contents of Documents directory
    NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@",
          [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error]);
```

and i am checking whether its there or not using..

```
 // fileExists is a BOOL variable
          fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]; 
         NSLog(@"Boolean value:=%d",fileExists);
        if ( fileExists  == 0 ) 
        {
           .......
          ........
        }
```

but each time i runs the app it returns the '0' (means the BOOL variable fileExists) . 
please some one will tell me the way to accomplish my task, I am end up with trying all the sides with this logic.

Comment: Check the string "filePath" before checking the file exist or not..

Comment: Did you set the string "filePath" before checking?

Comment: @ anusha : thanks for your updates , actually i solved it with the help of "NSUserDefaults"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i use the NSUserDefaults for this.

first upon for checking that whether the user is opening the app first time i check the value for the first object of NSUserDefault like

```
 //defaults is a object of NSUserDefault 
NSString *URLEntered =[defaults objectForKey:@"URLISENTERED"];
if (!URLEntered)  {

        [defaults setValue:@"0" forKey:@"URLISENTERED"];
    }
```

the URLEntered returns null at first time, so i set the value 0 for Key URLISENTERED

and i allowed users to enter the URL of there organizations server,
within that i set the valu for key URLISENTERED as a 1 , like

```
[defaults setValue:@"1" forKey:@"URLISENTERED"];
```

and at the same time i take one more object of NSUserDefault to store the URL of the server and stored that like

```
// defaultURL is the object of NSUserDefault, and main URL is the URL of server user entered

[defaultURL setValue:mainURL forKey:@"mainURL"];
```

so next when the user again logins to the app the value of

```
[defaults objectForKey:@"URLISENTERED"]
```

is 1 as we set and that time i navigated user to login screen directly , and have fetched the value of mainURL using

```
mainURL=[defaultURL objectForKey:@"mainURL"];
```

and used this URL for further use.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your problem your can use **NSUserDefault** or **plist**

1. Using plist:

   ```
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
   NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
   NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"plist.plist"]; 
   NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

   if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path]) 
   {
       path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"plist.plist"] ];
   }

   NSMutableDictionary *data;
   NSString *userURL ;

   if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path]) 
   {
               data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
               //To retrieve the data from the plist
               NSMutableDictionary *savedURL= [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];

   userURL = [savedURL objectForKey:@"USER_URL"];
   NSLog(@"%@",userURL);
            // present login detail or more stuff with userURL
   }
   else
   {

       userURL = // prompt for user to enter URL 
       data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
      [data setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:value] forKey:@"USER_URL"];
      [data writeToFile: path atomically:YES];

   }
   ```
2. Using NSUserDefault:

   ```
   NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   NSString *userURL = [defaults objectForKey:@"USER_URL"];
   if(userURL) {
           NSLog(@"%@",userURL);
           //present login detail or more stuff with userURL
   }
   else {
   userURL = // prompt for userURL
   [defaults setObject:userURL forKey:@"USER_URL"];
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you want to check URL on client . you can accomplish this task using sqlite database.

Comment: ya Mohd we can make the use of sqlite but i found it some what complicated as i am not much familiar with sqlite, So i used the NSUserDefault and its done.